# How to save a phpthumb output into a file?

Tags: php, phpthumb

I am trying to save PhpThumb output. As what I could find on-line was not sufficient or too complex, I would like to ask if any one knows how to it?

```
$thumb_src="\"phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../apartmentsPhotos/".$num['ref']."/1.JPG&h=119&q=100\"";

echo" '<'img src=".$thumb_src />";
```

So what I want to do is to save the img src into an Image.

(So far I was creating the thumbnails on the fly but it seems that google and my web server don´t like it too much. Saving the thumbnails will ensure that in no time I will have all my thumbnails in real files and then I will use this function just for new content.)

Answer (score 1):

From phpThumb's FAQ

> The best way is to call `phpThumb` as an object and call `RenderToFile()` to save the
>   thumbnail to whatever filename you want. See `/demo/phpThumb.demo.object.php` for an example.   The other way is to use the `'file'` parameter (see `/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt`) but this parameter is deprecated and does not work in `phpThumb v1.7.5` and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have generated the URL with this line you posted:

```
$thumb_src="\"phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../apartmentsPhotos/".$num['ref']."/1.JPG&h=119&q=100\"";
```

Pass it as a $_GET variable to another page, call it serveThumb.php:

```
if (!isset($_GET['img']))
      exit;

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['img']);
```

You might have to add your own validation to serveThumb.php. Now you can save the result of serveThumb.php as a JPG.

Alternatively, save the contents of the image as a JPG file.

```
if (!isset($_GET['img']))
      exit;

$img = file_get_contents($_GET['img']);
file_put_contents("myImage.jpg", $img);
```

Comment: Cant I do it in the same page?Why is it needed to pass it to a different page?

Thanks

Comment: True, you can just save the contents of the URL in $thumb_src as an image.

Comment: Hi SimpleCoder!
That´s what I am trying to do but don´t know how...Ori